# the property called message of the HttpException argument of the catch function has not the statusCode

Tags: nestjs

the property called message of the HttpException argument of the catch function when I have a 400 error return

```
[
 {
  "target": {
    "password": "xxxxxx"
  },
  "property": "
  "children": [],
  "constraints": {
    "maxLength": "Este campo no debe tener mas de 30 caracteres",
    "isString": "Este campo debería contener un string",
    "isNotEmpty": "Este campo no puede estar vacío"
  }
 }
]
```

But I expected to receive

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": [
   {
    "target": {
      "password": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "property": "
    "children": [],
    "constraints": {
      "maxLength": "Este campo no debe tener mas de 30 caracteres",
      "isString": "Este campo deberia contener un string",
      "isNotEmpty": "Este campo no puede estar vacío"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class ExceptionHandler implements ExceptionFilter {

  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    ...
    const statusCode = exception.message.statusCode;//undefined
    ...

    response
    .status(statusCode)//so here there is an error
    .json(json);
  }
}



@Controller('user')
export class UserController {

  @Post('create')
  create(@Body() user: User) {//the error occurred when the user 
                                object do not pass validations
    return user;
  }

  ...
}



export class User {

  readonly id: number;

  @IsNotEmpty({ message: TXT_14 })
  @IsString({ message: TXT_15 })
  @MaxLength(30, { message: TXT_16 })
  readonly username: string;

  @IsNotEmpty({ message: TXT_14 })
  @IsString({ message: TXT_15 })
  @MaxLength(30, { message: TXT_16 })
  readonly password: string;
}
```

### Error thrown

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0qgw.png)

### Environment

Nest version: 5.4.0

For Tooling issues:

- Node version: 10.9.0
- Platform:  Mac

Sorry for my broken English :)

Comment: Are you using the Nest built in ValidationPipe? Just using @Body isn't enough to cause validation to happen like this

Comment: In a previous api that I built with nestjs 5.4.0 the built-in ValidationPipe thrown HttpException but in latest version does not do that, so, I had to build my own ValidationPipe, but thank you for your answer and time!! :)